# Cannot install MySQL 8 on KDE neon (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: 64-bit, mysql, ubuntu-20.04

Fresh installed KDE Neon based on Ubuntu 20.04.

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

and the result is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
Investigating (0) mysql-server:amd64 < none -> 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4 @un puN Ib >
Broken mysql-server:amd64 Depends on mysql-server-8.0:amd64 < none | 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4 @un uH >
  Considering mysql-server-8.0:amd64 1 as a solution to mysql-server:amd64 9999
  Re-Instated mariadb-common:amd64
  Re-Instated mariadb-client-core-10.3:amd64
  Re-Instated mysql-client-core-8.0:amd64
  Re-Instated mysql-client-8.0:amd64
    Reinst Failed early because of mysql-server-core-8.0:amd64
  Considering mysql-server-8.0:amd64 1 as a solution to mysql-server:amd64 9999
Investigating (0) mariadb-client-core-10.3:amd64 < none -> 1:10.3.22-1ubuntu1 @un uN Ib >
Broken mariadb-client-core-10.3:amd64 Conflicts on mysql-client-8.0:amd64 < none -> 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4 @un uN >
  Considering mysql-client-8.0:amd64 0 as a solution to mariadb-client-core-10.3:amd64 0
  Holding Back mariadb-client-core-10.3:amd64 rather than change mysql-client-8.0:amd64
Investigating (0) mysql-client-core-8.0:amd64 < none -> 0.4+p20.04+git20201012.1101 @un uN Ib >
Broken mysql-client-core-8.0:amd64 Depends on mariadb-client-core-10.3:amd64 < none | 1:10.3.22-1ubuntu1 @un uH >
  Considering mariadb-client-core-10.3:amd64 0 as a solution to mysql-client-core-8.0:amd64 0
  Holding Back mysql-client-core-8.0:amd64 rather than change mariadb-client-core-10.3:amd64
Investigating (0) mysql-client-8.0:amd64 < none -> 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4 @un uN Ib >
Broken mysql-client-8.0:amd64 Depends on mysql-client-core-8.0:amd64 < none | 0.4+p20.04+git20201012.1101 @un uH >
  Considering mysql-client-core-8.0:amd64 0 as a solution to mysql-client-8.0:amd64 0
  Holding Back mysql-client-8.0:amd64 rather than change mysql-client-core-8.0:amd64
Investigating (1) mysql-server:amd64 < none -> 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4 @un puN Ib >
Broken mysql-server:amd64 Depends on mysql-server-8.0:amd64 < none | 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4 @un uH >
  Considering mysql-server-8.0:amd64 1 as a solution to mysql-server:amd64 9999
  Considering mysql-server-8.0:amd64 1 as a solution to mysql-server:amd64 9999
Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-8.0 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Tested on 2 different PC, fresh install.

Is this a general problem? or just broken/canceled at origin?

Answer (score 1):

it seems to be this file fault, removing it allows me to install. Its akoladi compatibility problems fault.

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/50-neon-mariadb
```